# CMake: automatically figure out command to activate python virtual environment

Tags: python, cmake, virtualenv

My CMake project add some custom commands, running python scripts, like this

```
add_custom_target(custom_target
                  COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py
)
```

Mostly always python interpreter is launched from a virtual environment. Python scripts import numpy and it is better to activate that environment before launching them: `source /path/bin/activate && python ./script.py`

However, I'm working on Windows, as well as some of my team mates.  Usually we launch CMake-gui from Start menu. Therefore, it doesn't have activated python environment. Therefore, it is better to place virtualenv activation inside custom commands, like below:

```
add_custom_target(custom_target
                  COMMAND source /path/to/venv/bin/activate && ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py
)
```

or for windows

```
add_custom_target(custom_target
                  COMMAND c:\Anaconda\condabin\conda activate py37 && ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py
)
```

Since we have Anaconda and CPython, we have at least two kinds of virtual environment activation commands: `conda activate venv` and `/path/to/venv/bin/activate`

I have tried to parse `Python3_INTERPRETER_ID` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#result-variables). However, this variable contains just "Python" and therefore is unreliable.

Studying sources of the FindPython CMake module shows that it parses output of `python -V`.

However, it looks like Anaconda is trying to mimic CPython:

```
(py37) C:\work>python -V
Python 3.7.7

(py37) C:\work>python
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So, my question: Is it possible to robustly automatically figure out activation command?

Comment: Can you just use `IF(WIN32)` and have different code for that?

Comment: Yes, I can. However, there are still several variants of python activation

Comment: I guess you may need to have the user tell CMake which one to use, perhaps via an environment variable if you don't have another way.